# Rebuilding the rpm package

Tags: linux, rpm, build, rhel-6

ALL,

I'm a long time Gentoo user.
Unfortunately I found a job where the primary distro is RHEL with different distribution system and different installation process.

My problem is I need to rebuild  one of the packages. I have the SRPM file and I'm trying to do that but failing.

Trying to use [this](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/patching_rpms.php) and [this](http://vdt.cs.wisc.edu/internal/native/using-srpm.html) but those links are not for the RHEL and I don't have enough knowledge to add 2 and 2 together.

Can anyone give me simple step by step instruction on how to rebuild the rpm? What I need is to change the configure line (remove 1 parameter) and rebuild.

Questions I have:

1.Do I create the directories such as SPEC, SOURCES etc in the very beginning or after I unpack the srpm?

2. How do I unpack the rpm if the directory are already been created?
3. Do I haver to issue all those commands in second link in order to finish the build process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is  rpmbuild (its a package)

sudo yum/dnf install rpmbuild

$ rpmdev-setup (from /home or build env  as it will create the needed SPEC SOURCES RPMs SRPMs and needed arch folders in $pwd.

Once you have that rpmbuild --help  ( there are a ton of rebuild options for rebuilding from the srpm / spec file  --for  rpm / just dependencies etc etc.

once built look in RPMs/{noarch,i386,x86_64} accordingly and then either run:

cd /path/chosen for rpmbuild

sudo rpm -iVh (or sudo yum/dnf install) . /$pkgname